# IOS inserting a row into UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a deadline coming up for this project and I've been working hard on it and so I'm pretty tired right now. I don't know if I'm just being stupid and blind to what I'm doing wrong but I have a problem that I need help with.

So, I'm trying to implement a sort of "expanding tableview setup" (like in IOS 7 calendar where you tap on the start and end dates and a cell pops in with a date picker). I have two different cells that can be displayed under a tapped cell. It works perfectly except for the actual cell, when I insert a row the wrong cell is displayed. I'll give some context... I have two cells in section 0, when you tap on the first cell it inserts a cell below it that should be a picker cell. Instead it inserts the same call as in row 1 of the unmodified tableview.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@interface AddMealTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL datePickerEnabled;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL pickerEnabled;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *datePickerIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *pickerIndexPath;

@end

@implementation AddMealTableViewController


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 2 + (self.datePickerEnabled) + (self.pickerEnabled);
            break;

        default:
            return self.mealComponents.count;
            break;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                TimeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TimeCell"];
                cell.timeLabel.text = @"Now";
                cell.mealTypeLabel.text = self.selectedMealType;
                return cell;
            }
            else if (indexPath == self.datePickerIndexPath) {
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DateCell"];
                return cell;
            }
            else if (indexPath == self.pickerIndexPath) {    
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PickerCell"];
                return cell;
            }
            else {
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MealTypeCell"];

                cell.textLabel.text = @"Meal Type";
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.selectedMealType;
                return cell;
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            ComponentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ComponentCell"];
            if (!cell) {
                cell = [ComponentCell new];
            }
            MealComponent *mc = self.mealComponents[indexPath.row];
            [cell setUpWithComponent:mc];
            return cell;
            break;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath == self.datePickerIndexPath || indexPath == self.pickerIndexPath) {
            return 200;
        }
        return self.tableView.rowHeight;
    }
    return 70;
}

- (void)toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0]];

    if (self.datePickerEnabled)
    {
        self.datePickerEnabled = NO;
        self.datePickerIndexPath = nil;
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
    else
    {
        self.datePickerIndexPath = indexPaths.lastObject;
        self.datePickerEnabled = YES;

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)togglePickerForSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0]];

    if (self.pickerEnabled)
    {
        self.pickerEnabled = NO;
        self.pickerIndexPath = nil;
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
    else
    {
        self.pickerIndexPath = indexPaths.lastObject;
        self.pickerEnabled = YES;


        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqual: @"TimeCell"]) {
            [self toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        else if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqual: @"MealTypeCell"]) {
            [self togglePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas? I really can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Please don't put [SOLVED] in the title. Selecting the answer that solved your problem, which you already did, is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you change the height of date picker cell from 0 to 200 instead insert (or delete) the date picker cell. I think this is more simple.(This is what I'm used to implement that)

when `[tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` is called, you just call `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]` to update cell.

You can managed the height of cell in `[tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:]` you already know.

[edited]

I examine your code again.

change `else if (indexPath == self.datePickefIndexPath)` to `else if([indexPath isEqual:self.datePickerIndexPath])` in `[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`

Comment: Oh wow thank-you how stupid of me. That works perfectly now. I think using "==" compares pointers not the object itself. Thank-you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to handle this kind of things. You really don't need to insert or delete cell, just modify the cell height from 0 to the proper height. To do this, you can set a flag to check whether the cell's expanded or not.